# Any alternative way to check if network location provider is enabled?

Tags: java, android, location

When i check

```
boolean networkReady=manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

i get true on some Samsung phones, eventhough the wireless location is not allowed in settings.

Is there any other way to check this setting and to get the correct value on all phones?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Attached below some nice network util functions I've been using across my apps, all works like a charm!
and for location polling, definitely -> https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll

hope this helps...

```
public static boolean checkInternetConnection(Context context) {

    ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    // ARE WE CONNECTED TO THE NET?
    if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
            && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
            && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        Log.w(TAG, "Internet Connection NOT Present");
        return false;
    }
}
    public static boolean isConnAvailAndNotRoaming(Context context) {

    ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
            && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
            && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {

        if(!conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isRoaming())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    } else {
        Log.w(TAG, "Internet Connection NOT Present");
        return false;
    }
}
    public static boolean isRoaming(Context context) {

    ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    return (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo()!=null && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isRoaming());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also try like this:

```
public boolean isDataConnectionAvailable(Context context){
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if(info == null)
            return false;

        return connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
}

public boolean isGpsEnabled(LocationManager manager){
        if ( !manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
}

public boolean isLocationByNetworkEnabled(LocationManager manager){
        if ( !manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER ) ) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the provider in the list returned by [getProviders(true);](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getProviders%28boolean%29) as well? Perhaps that device thinks that the network location provider should always be enabled to provide a PASSIVE_PROVIDER? Seems broken to me. Which Samsung devices do you see this behaviour on?